# I want to justify align <p> tag in <img> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

When I hover an img, I want to show a Paragraph. 
The code which I have now does that, but the problem is, the paragraph is wider than the img. I want it exactly as the width as the img (but I dont want to give a width px) Here is my code, but i removed a few code lines from the css, I left the important ones (I also dont know why the jquery doesnt work since i dont have any experience in jquery and jsfiddle)

[jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gpohz45b/)

```
    <div class="container pt">
        <div class="row mt centered">   
            <h1>Bestuur</h1>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a class="zoom green">
                    <span class="test">
                        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/gXHM44W.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />
                    </span>
                    <p>"Ik ben Samir Aliyev en ik ben 18 jaar oud.</br> AZJN is altijd mijn passie geweest, door AZJN heb ik heel veel sociale contacten gekregen binnen Nederland met Azerbeidzjaanse jongeren. Ik heb mezelf niet alleen ontwikkeld qua sociaal zijn maar ook op zakelijke manieren. Zo hebben we bijvoorbeeld heel veel brieven geschreven naar formele instanties, evenementen georganiseerd die voor goede doelen waren en buitenlanders kennis laten maken met Azerbeidzjan. Meestal ben ik bezig met multimedia van AZJN, dus tijdens evenementen zie je me meestal met een Foto-apparaat lopen of een Camera. Ik zit al vanaf het begin in het AZJN-team en ik ben ook niet van plan om eruit te stappen! "</p>
                    <p>test</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you open to making mark up changes? You could give the image and paragraph a wrapper and float that. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/gpohz45b/2/ Or, would JavaScript be okay to calculate the width and apply it on hover?

Comment: This pic of the cat is hilarious. ++

Comment: Another simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ms01nmbm/1/

Comment: You have not closed the anchor.

Comment: Your solution is indeed good! thanks @DanFromGermany

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use width? You know you can also use `width: 100%`
or similar in your css if you don't want to use fixed widths. You also seem to have forgotten to close some tags properly. If you can somehow manage I would try and do this with CSS, because this really is more a problem of how to arrange things on the screen (-->CSS). So try `width: 100%` or place the `<p>` within the image tag (see below) and position it with relative positioning (`position: relative; left: ??px/em/% right: ??px/em/% top: ... bottom: ...`)

Most certainly close tags as showed here below:

```
<div class="container pt">
        <div class="row mt centered">   
        <h1>Bestuur</h1>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a class="zoom green"></a><img src="http://i.imgur.com/gXHM44W.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" class="test">

<p>"Ik ben Samir Aliyev en ik ben 18 jaar oud.</br> AZJN is altijd mijn passie geweest, door AZJN heb ik heel veel sociale contacten gekregen binnen Nederland met Azerbeidzjaanse jongeren. Ik heb mezelf niet alleen ontwikkeld qua sociaal zijn maar ook op zakelijke manieren. Zo hebben we bijvoorbeeld heel veel brieven geschreven naar formele instanties, evenementen georganiseerd die voor goede doelen waren en buitenlanders kennis laten maken met Azerbeidzjan. Meestal ben ik bezig met multimedia van AZJN, dus tijdens evenementen zie je me meestal met een Foto-apparaat lopen of een Camera. Ik zit al vanaf het begin in het AZJN-team en ik ben ook niet van plan om eruit te stappen! "</p></img>

                <p>test</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a javascript function that assigns the width of the image to the text div. I've added ID's to the img tag and the text div (which was a `<p>` tag)

```js
function showText(divId,imgId) {

 document.getElementById(divId).style.visibility = "visible";
 document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById(divId).style.width = document.getElementById(imgId).offsetWidth + "px";
}

function hideText(divId) {
 document.getElementById(divId).style.visibility = "hidden";
 document.getElementById(divId).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="container pt">
        <div class="row mt centered">   
        <h1>Bestuur</h1>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <a class="zoom green">
                <span class="test"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/gXHM44W.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" onmouseover="showText('theText',this.id)" onmouseout="hideText('theText')" id="theImg"></span>
                <div id="theText" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;">
                "Ik ben Samir Aliyev en ik ben 18 jaar oud.</br> AZJN is altijd mijn passie geweest, door AZJN heb ik heel veel sociale contacten gekregen binnen Nederland met Azerbeidzjaanse jongeren.
                 Ik heb mezelf niet alleen ontwikkeld qua sociaal zijn maar ook op zakelijke manieren. Zo hebben we bijvoorbeeld heel veel brieven geschreven naar formele instanties, evenementen georganiseerd
                  die voor goede doelen waren en buitenlanders kennis laten maken met Azerbeidzjan. Meestal ben ik bezig met multimedia van AZJN, dus tijdens evenementen zie je me meestal met een Foto-apparaat
                   lopen of een Camera. Ik zit al vanaf het begin in het AZJN-team en ik ben ook niet van plan om eruit te stappen! "</div>
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the code shows the p,which is nice, but it doesn't show up on the img

Comment: Ok sorry, I thought you wanted it underneath the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make `a` element inline-block instead of block:

```
.zoom {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/gpohz45b/3/

Comment: I don't think he wants the text over the image.

Comment: Hm.. *The code which I have now does that, but the problem is, the paragraph is wider than the img.*. Why do you think OP doesn't want text over image?

Comment: Because the text over the image is unreadable, and it doesn't make sense to do so. I'm just guessing.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Well it's pretty common way to present some info in overlay over images, etc. It's not readable because of styles, it can be good-looking too. For example, https://jsfiddle.net/gpohz45b/5/

Comment: Sure but he didn't say he wanted the text over the image.

Comment: @DanielWilliams Well this statement "*When I hover an img, I want to show a Paragraph. The code which I have now does that, but the problem is, the paragraph is wider than the img.*" - sounds to me like, text over image is exactly what OP needs, providing that in the demo posted text is indeed over the image. But anyway, let OP come and decide.

Comment: I want to show text on the img, like @Dfsq suggested, but the text on the whole img no white spaces